# Raspberry PI / Kodi wont start after upgrading raspbian to buster version

Tags: raspbian, kodi

Raspberry pi 2 b, raspbian buster - stable version

I have problem with starting Kodi on my raspberry PI. Before upgrading raspbian from stretch to buster kodi works great. After upgrading to buster kodi stops working.

below is crashlog from kodi

```
############## Kodi CRASH LOG ###############

################ SYSTEM INFO ################
 Date: pon, 1 lip 2019, 16:45:45 CEST
 Kodi Options: 
 Arch: armv7l
 Kernel: Linux 4.19.56-v7+ #1242 SMP Wed Jun 26 17:31:47 BST 2019
 Release: Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
############## END SYSTEM INFO ##############

############### STACK TRACE #################
############# END STACK TRACE ###############

################# LOG FILE ##################

﻿16:45:15.273 T:1830922080  NOTICE: special://profile/ is mapped to: special://masterprofile/
16:45:15.273 T:1830922080  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
16:45:15.274 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Starting Kodi from Debian (17.6 Debian package version: 2:17.6+dfsg1-4+b1). Platform: Linux ARM 32-bit
16:45:15.274 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Using Release Kodi from Debian x32 build
16:45:15.274 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Kodi from Debian compiled from 2:17.6+dfsg1-4+b1 by GCC 8.2.0 for Linux ARM 32-bit version 4.18.20 (266772)
16:45:15.274 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Running on Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster), kernel: Linux ARM 32-bit version 4.19.56-v7+
16:45:15.274 T:1830922080  NOTICE: FFmpeg version/source: 4.1.3-1+rpt1
16:45:15.274 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Host CPU: ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l), 4 cores available
16:45:15.274 T:1830922080  NOTICE: ARM Features: Neon disabled
16:45:15.274 T:1830922080  NOTICE: special://xbmc/ is mapped to: /usr/share/kodi
16:45:15.274 T:1830922080  NOTICE: special://xbmcbin/ is mapped to: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/kodi
16:45:15.274 T:1830922080  NOTICE: special://xbmcbinaddons/ is mapped to: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/kodi/addons
16:45:15.274 T:1830922080  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/ is mapped to: /home/pi/.kodi/userdata
16:45:15.275 T:1830922080  NOTICE: special://envhome/ is mapped to: /home/pi
16:45:15.275 T:1830922080  NOTICE: special://home/ is mapped to: /home/pi/.kodi
16:45:15.275 T:1830922080  NOTICE: special://temp/ is mapped to: /home/pi/.kodi/temp
16:45:15.275 T:1830922080  NOTICE: special://logpath/ is mapped to: /home/pi/.kodi/temp
16:45:15.275 T:1830922080  NOTICE: The executable running is: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/kodi/kodi.bin
16:45:15.275 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Local hostname: raspberrypi
16:45:15.275 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Log File is located: /home/pi/.kodi/temp//kodi.log
16:45:15.275 T:1830922080  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
16:45:15.287 T:1830922080   ERROR: DBus: Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown - The name org.freedesktop.UPower was not provided by any .service files
16:45:15.453 T:1830922080  NOTICE: load settings...
16:45:15.528 T:1830922080   ERROR: PulseAudio: Failed to connect context
16:45:15.528 T:1830922080  NOTICE: PulseAudio might not be running. Context was not created.
16:45:15.590 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Found 1 Lists of Devices
16:45:15.590 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Enumerated ALSA devices:
16:45:15.590 T:1830922080  NOTICE:     Device 1
16:45:15.591 T:1830922080  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : @
16:45:15.591 T:1830922080  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Default (bcm2835 ALSA bcm2835 ALSA)
16:45:15.591 T:1830922080  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra:
16:45:15.591 T:1830922080  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
16:45:15.591 T:1830922080  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR
16:45:15.591 T:1830922080  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000
16:45:15.591 T:1830922080  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S16LE,AE_FMT_U8
16:45:15.591 T:1830922080  NOTICE:         m_streamTypes     : No passthrough capabilities
16:45:15.609 T:1830922080  NOTICE: No settings file to load (special://xbmc/system/advancedsettings.xml)
16:45:15.609 T:1830922080  NOTICE: No settings file to load (special://masterprofile/advancedsettings.xml)
16:45:15.609 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Default Video Player: VideoPlayer
16:45:15.609 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Default Audio Player: paplayer
16:45:15.609 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Disabled debug logging due to GUI setting. Level 0.
16:45:15.609 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Log level changed to "LOG_LEVEL_NORMAL"
16:45:15.610 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Loading player core factory settings from special://xbmc/system/playercorefactory.xml.
16:45:15.611 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Loaded playercorefactory configuration
16:45:15.611 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Loading player core factory settings from special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml.
16:45:15.611 T:1830922080  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml does not exist. Skipping.
16:45:15.642 T:1830922080  NOTICE: Running database version Addons27
16:45:15.747 T:1830922080  NOTICE: ADDONS: Using repository repository.xbmc.org
16:45:15.837 T:1830922080   ERROR: X11 Error: No Display found
16:45:15.837 T:1830922080   FATAL: CApplication::Create: Unable to init windowing system


############### END LOG FILE ################

############ END Kodi CRASH LOG #############
```

Trying find solution on google but there are old solution, none work for me.

this is the problem

```
16:45:15.837 T:1830922080   ERROR: X11 Error: No Display found
16:45:15.837 T:1830922080   FATAL: CApplication::Create: Unable to init windowing system
```

Anyone have problem like that?

Answer (score 1):

Note there are two versions of Kodi wandering around:
apt-cache showpkg kodi | tail -3

2:18.2-1~stretch - xbmc-standalone (= ) xbmc-data (= ) xbmc (= ) kodi-standalone (= ) kodi-skin-estuary (= ) kodi-data (= )

2:17.6+dfsg1-4+b1 - kodi-api-pvr (= 5.2.1) kodi-api-guilib (= 5.11.0)

The dfsg1 versions are the "general" ones from debian; they are not optimised for Raspberry Pi (no hardware acceleration) and need xorg .
Better choice for the Raspberry Pi are the ~stretch or ~jessie versions; they are hosted at http://archive.raspberrypi.org, so you will need a file in your /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory, e.g. kodi.list, containing the line:
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui

Run apt-get update to update your package lists.
If you have upgraded to Raspbian Buster you will get a dependency conflict, because 
kodi-bin 2:18.2-1~stretch needs libcurl3, and buster only provides libcurl4.

You will need to downgrade libcurl4 to libcurl3, and then you can install kodi 2:18.2-1~stretch (which will work fine on Raspbian Buster).
Easiest is to use aptitude install kodi=2:18.2-1~stretch, because this will give you scenarios to resolve the conflicts.
You have to temporarily change your "buster" references to "stretch" to do this downgrade.

Comment: thanks for Your answer ill check it. For now i have back to stretch version of raspbian but with Your answer i can check buster. Ill let know is this work for me

Comment: If you save the files from libcurl and libmariadbclient18 you can start kodi by replacing the Execstart =  line in /etc/systemd/system/kodi.service by:
 
Execstart = env LD_PRELOAD="/usr/local/src/libcurl.so.3 /usr/local/src/libmariadbclient.so.18" /usr/bin/kodi

In /usr/local/src I have:
/usr/local/src/libcurl.so.3 -> libcurl.so.4.4.0
/usr/local/src/libcurl.so.4.4.0
 /usr/local/src/libmariadbclient.so.18 -> libmariadbclient.so.18.0.0
/usr/local/src/libmariadbclient.so.18.0.0

This way you can upgrade to buster dependencies, and still run kodi with the libraries it needs from stretch

Comment: nice, i have to try

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problem on buster. Solved by install xorg:

```
sudo apt install xorg
```

and start kodi in this way:

```
sudo xinit kodi-standalone
```

Comment: hi, TY I'll check it and let here know if it works for me